# How to differentiate between a regular file and a symbolic link?

Tags: c, linux, posix, symlink

I am dealing with symbolic links using C posix in linux.

I detect a file and I have to differentiate between a regular file and a symbolic link.

Now I do the next:

```c
if(S_ISREG(direct_info.st_mode)) {
   // deal with regular file
}
else if(S_ISLNK(direct_info.st_mode)) {
   // deal with symbolic link
}
```

the problem is that when the file is a symbolic link the flow of the execution enter at the first if. That is, when is a symbolic link also enter in the `S_ISREG` condition. So, what can i do to distinguish between both?

Comment: Check if it's a link first.

Comment: How did you obtain `direct_info`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using `stat()` to get the file modes. `stat()` actually returns the info about the target, not the link itself.
So, in order to get the information about the link itself you need to use [`lstat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).